# Intel Device 5912 graphic not recongnised on Mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics

I am trying to get my Dell Optiplex 7050 (uses an integrated Intel video processor) to recognize the graphic hardware Intel Device 5912.

OS: Mint 17.3 Rosa

When I run `lspci -knn` it says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5912] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:07a1]
```

When I run `inxi -b` it says:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5912
       Display Server: X.Org 1.16.0 drivers: fbdev,intel (unloaded: vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@77.0hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
```

I download the older version of intel linux graphic installer from https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.10/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.1.0-0intel1_i386.deb

and I run:

```
 sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.1.0-0intel1_i386.deb
```

ThenI got this error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of intel-linux-graphics-installer:
intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on ttf-ancient-fonts.
intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on aptdaemon.
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` doesn't search for the package dependencies so to install them command run

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

after running the `dpkg -i` command.

Quoting the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> `-f`, `--fix-broken`
> Fix. Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. Any package(s) that are specified must completely correct the problem. This option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention. Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations.